# Valgrind configure build script "Syntax Error" OSX Monterey - how to fix?

Tags: valgrind

I'm trying to build Valgrind 3.19.0 on OSX monterey and when i run the configure script i get a syntax error at line 6594:

```
checking for diff -u... yes
./configure: line 6594: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./configure: line 6594: `    '''
```

This is the code sippet of the configure script where the error is occuring.

```
for as_dir in $PATH
do
  IFS=$as_save_IFS
  case $as_dir in #(((
    ''
 as_dir=./ ;;
    */) ;;
    *) as_dir=$as_dir/ ;;
```

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacOS Valgrind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009780/macos-valgrind-alternative)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792467/memory-check-on-macos-12-monterey/69808694#69808694 even better

Comment: oh ok, so it just wont build on monterey. The issue im having specifically is a syntax error in the bash script, but it sounds like even if i get that fixed ill have other problems. Thank you for pointing those threads out. I didnt see them when i was researching.